# azure api manager unable to replicate changes from git mirroring

Tags: git, azure, azure-api-management

We are having centralize git repo where all teams commit changes.

```
https://mycentralizerepo.scm.azure-api.net
```

in order to make changes in this repo to be available in other repo we do mirroring. with following steps. consider for example we need to replicate changes from mycentralizerepo to mydevazureapimanagerrepo

```
git clone --bare https://mycentralizerepo.scm.azure-api.net
cd mycentralizerepo.scm.azure-api.net.git
git push --mirror https://mydevazureapimanagerrepo.scm.azure-api.net
```

once done this process i perform save and deploy my changes from azure portal but it does not replicate my changes from centrailize repo (api added in centralize repo)

i can see this process works perfectly well for normal bitbucket repositories.
can someone explain me if i am missing someting?

Comment: Why are you trying this approach? Are you looking for setting up CI/CD for APIM? Then you should go with Azure DevOps routes.

Comment: i got solution for this problem. once i push my code to mydevazureapimanagerrepo i need to deploy changes and not save changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"once done this process i perform save and deploy" - on which services "save" and "deploy" were run?

The correct order is:

1. Do the changes on your source apim instance portal (mycentralizerepo).
2. Run "Save" on the source apim instance (mycentralizerepo). This will "transfer" data from apim DB to the repo. Now source repo has all desired data.
3. Apply your steps:

   - git clone --bare https://mycentralizerepo.scm.azure-api.net
   - cd mycentralizerepo.scm.azure-api.net.git
   - git push --mirror https://mydevazureapimanagerrepo.scm.azure-api.net

So after this the destination apim (mydevazureapimanagerrepo) has a repo copied from the source apim.

4. Run "Deploy" operation on the destination apim (mydevazureapimanagerrepo). This will take the repo and "transfer" it to the apim DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-api-management-devops-example) recommendation from Microsoft.

Comment: thanks for your response. as per my understanding pull request are not specific to git but specific to github and bitbucket. hence it has limitations.